# Semi-transparent "watermark" in MAC OS display

Tags: macos, terminal, core-graphics, display

It is possible to put in top of the all windows, and app in MAC OS, set somehow extra semi-transparent layer with custom graphic? This graphic should be visible system wide, and should be not active when clicking on it, it should be only visible... The as closest match what I want to archive is, when you imagine semitransparent watermark on display.

Please see the screenshots for definite picture of what I want to archive:

[image]

It is possible to make via some software or terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a Cocoa app that displays a window behaving like what you want.  The window should be created with a style mask of `NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless`.  To put the window in front of most other windows, experiment with the `level` property.  To ignore mouse clicks, set the `ignoresMouseEvents` property to YES.  To make the window transparent, set the `opaque` property to NO and set the `backgroundColor` property to `[NSColor clearColor]`.  And of course you'd have to put a view in there that draws what you want.